# Error - Playa’s var_prefix parameter

Tags: playa

I'm having trouble getting this error resolved:

> .... is using the deprecated {child:url_title} tag. Please use Playa’s
>   var_prefix parameter instead

This is my code:

```
{exp:playa:parents field="artist-relationship-playa" orderby="artworks-order" sort="asc"}
        {if "{show-on-website}" == "y"}
            <a href="{site_url}artists/{child:url_title}/{url_title}">{embed="artists/_artist-artworks-embed" entry_id="{entry_id}"}</a>
        {/if}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

This code is inside a **channel** tag pair.

What should I change about this code to make is work?

Comment: Which version are you using? 4.4 had a lot of bug, 4.4.1 has just been released

Comment: I'm using 4.4. Will upgrade now. However my errors have nothing to do with this. It's just my lack of knowledge.

Comment: This is the code that got it to work:

    {exp:playa:parents field="artist-relationship-playa" orderby="artworks-order" sort="asc" var_prefix="artworks"}
          {if "{artworks:show-on-website}" == "y"}
             <a href="{site_url}artists/{url_title}/{artworks:url_title}">...</a>
          {/if}
    {/exp:playa:parents}
Just so that others want to know how it works. When using var_prefix, all variables inside that playa tag pair are rendered as if they where not. Only if you prefix your variable with your var_prefix value, will it be rendered as it would previously... get it :)

Comment: That's a beautiful explanation, Louis. I'm glad you figured it out! It'd be awesome if you posted this as an answer and accepted it.  And thank you for following up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I get how it works now.
This is the code that got it to work:

```
{exp:playa:parents field="artist-relationship-playa" orderby="artworks-order" sort="asc" var_prefix="artworks"}
      {if "{artworks:show-on-website}" == "y"}
         <a href="{site_url}artists/{url_title}/{artworks:url_title}">...</a>
      {/if}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Just so that others want to know how it works. When using var_prefix, all variables inside that playa tag pair are rendered as if they where not. Only if you prefix your variable with your var_prefix value, will it be rendered as it would previously... get it :)