# Where does the var_prefix come from in Playa?

Tags: add-on, playa

I tried commenting on [this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/error-playas-var-prefix-parameter), but it's closed. I am having a similar issue - the deprecated `{parent:field}` is working, but I'm sure won't forever. I'd like to switch to using the `var_prefix`, but I can't find where that is set.

I tried using the channel name `{channel:field}` - just not sure what `var_prefix` is in reference to.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products"}
    {accessories url_title="{segment_4}" limit="1"}
        {parent:title} product title
    {/accessories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The accessory is a child and accessories is the field name in the products field group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var_prefix tag is a parameter available to any of the [Playa module tags](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/index.html). It tells Playa to only parse variables that have a certain prefix. This is handy when you’re dealing with variable name conflicts, such as if you’re pulling in an entry with its own Playa tag:

```
{exp:playa:children channel="news" var_prefix="news"}
    {news:exp:playa:children channel="editors" var_prefix="editor"}
        {news:title} - {editor:title}
    {/news:exp:playa:children}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Comment: Ah, so it's defined in the loop - got it! Thanks!

Can I add a var_prefix to the parent `{exp:channel:entries}`? In my instance, I only have a channel entries loop and a Playa children loop. I've edited my post above to include the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out, I didn't actually need the opening channel entries loop, I was able to do it with all Playa tags.

```
{exp:playa:children url_title="{segment_4}" limit="1" var_prefix="accessories"}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="products" url_title="{segment_3}" var_prefix="products"}

        {products:title} - {accessories:accessory_description}

    {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Thanks @Ian.

Comment: You got it. The Playa tag handles (almost) all the same parameters the Channel Entries tag does and loops in the same way. It adds a few extra like `var_prefix` for some extra Playa specific functionality.