# var_prefix message in ee 2.8.1 dev log

Tags: playa, 2.8

I'm getting this message in **EE 2.8.1** dev logs with **Playa 4.4.5**:

> A template loaded on http://dev.tear.org.au/projects/ is using the
>   deprecated {parent:url_title} tag. Please use Playa’s var_prefix
>   parameter instead.

[This answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/error-playas-var-prefix-parameter) helped, but not enough.

I've seen the var_prefix docs concerning the module tags, but can't find info regarding the fieldtype tag, which is what I am using.

My code looks like this (simplified):

```
{exp:channel:entries...}
    {project_content} <-- PLAYA FIELD
    {content limit="1"}
        <h4>
            <a href="/projects/{parent:url_title}">{parent:title}</a>
        </h4>
    {/content}
    {/project_content}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**How would I need to modify my template to use the new parameter?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to prefix with Playa for what you're doing. You should just be able to use...

```
{exp:channel:entries...}
    {project_content}
        {content limit="1"}
            <h4><a href="/projects/{url_title}">{title}</a></h4>
        {/content}
    {/project_content}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The `var_prefix` parameter comes in handy when you want to do things like pagination for your Playa entries. You need to prefix it then so that it doesn't interfere with the main entry's pagination. But in your example, it shouldn't be required.

Comment: Hmmm... so why am I getting that warning in the dev log?

Comment: Are you still getting that in the log after updating the code to that in my answer? It does have a very slight difference from the one in your question.

Comment: Ah - missed that, sorry, and yes, it works without the prefix - thanks!